# Devise Token Auth - Not returning tokens to client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

Setting up devise_token_auth.

Keep running in to issues in the source code.

Ex:

```
def token_validation_response
  as_json(except: %i[tokens created_at updated_at])
end
```

It will be called from:

`SessionsController::create` > `render_create_success` > `token_validation_response`

It is my understanding that you need to get the token to the client and store it on the client side and send it with each request.
I am not sure how this is supposed to work if we do not give the token to the client and `except` it.

`except: %i[tokens created_at updated_at]`

Links to source:
https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/c92258038c05fcc8f6a0374ccce2e63b9f8d5312/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb#L36

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/c92258038c05fcc8f6a0374ccce2e63b9f8d5312/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb#L205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this might be useful to someone. The token comes in the header not the body.

Update:

I also needed to work around client side cors issues.

A few options that helped:

[Vue Axios CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883984/vue-axios-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin/66192977#66192977)

https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-and-why-you-should-avoid-cors-in-single-page-apps-db25452ad2f8

The easiest solution was executing chrome the command line:

`open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security`

Source: https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/