# POST call return CORS error even with right headers

Tags: ajax, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to make my first POST call and I am getting an error that says

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:8080'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is
> not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Following is my code

```
methods: {
 uploadData(){
      axios
        .post(
          "url",
          this.data,
      {
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
      }
        )
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Error", err);
        });
  }
}
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883984/vue-axios-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin) if the header sent is wrong it happens but I removed the headers. In the network tab, it says CORS error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by itself in preflight response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr)

Comment: @samuei I didn't understand the linked answer as I m very new to API so everything went above me. is there any good basic video tutorial ?

Comment: The "url" where you are post-ing your data must return HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,Accept,Origin`

Comment: You need to allow your frontend app in the CORS of your backend app. 100 seconds of video, explaining how it works: https://youtu.be/4KHiSt0oLJ0

Comment: What is "url" or did you remove the URL? Also can you show us your backend code, you're getting this error because you probably didn't setup CORS for your backend

Comment: What is the url your're trying to access ? it's a backend you control ? what is it ?

Comment: Are you using `node.js` on the backend?

Answer (score 2):

The server that you send your `POST` request to needs to include the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** in its **response**. which is the headers you specify in your request to the server running on `http://localhost:8080` in your case.

`headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}`

This is because it is up to the server to allow **cross-origin requests** and that it permits the Content-Type request header you send to it **(X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest)**. The client can never decide for itself that a given server should allow **CORS**.

**Links to learn more about CORS:**

To read more about how to find out **CORS** errors: [CORS errors doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors)

If your new to **CORS** you can read more about what it is here: [CORS doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Video that explains **CORS**: [REST - API CORS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzEEIiDytBI)

How to enable **CORS** in spring for example: [Java Spring Enable CORS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PovQ6aUeRgg)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of the error, it seems like you need to take care of 2 things.

1. Have your backend server send the appropriate 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with the correct value (either '*' or the URL from your request)
2. Create a route that will handle calls using the OPTIONS method, which returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' value.

There is a lot of info about CORS out there. I hope the following Youtube videos give you a more detailed overview:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPzMRoPDrFk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcLW5d0KAYE

The Mozilla Developer Network Website documents all the details about the preflight request that your browser is placing which has the error you reported as outcome.
[MDN Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests)

Answer (score 0):

1. as you have mentioned you are sending "headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}", i don't understand why you need to set this in header instead you this you can try it as
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},

```js
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
} 
 axios.post('/url',{headers:headers}).then((response)=>{
      
            
            if(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
```

2. But it's not enough to remove the CORS error you have to set the CORS property at server end , you can try the following code-

```html
        <?php 
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) 
        {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
            header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400");
        }

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='OPTIONS') 
        {
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH");         

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

            exit(0);
            }
        }
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is mainly on the backend side,**
Whenever you make API calls from say google.com(client) to yahoo.com(backend) it would fail since yahoo would not allow Google to access its data. (a Funny answer) but that is where Cross-origin-resource sharing would come into play, yahoo would allow a few kinds of requests from google.com, In order to achieve this a special kind of API request is first made called OPTIONS request a.k.a pre-flight check like the one done before an actual take-off of an airplane. based on the response of this OPTIONS request your POST, GET, PUT...etc would take-off.
therefore your backend needs this OPTIONS API request handled.

Hope this clears some doubt in the AIR