# How to auto submit form after values are set from api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

how to auto submit form after values of from are set after calling api

i want the form to auto submit after the values are successfully fetched from the api,

i used $refs.form.submit(), however, it doesn't work as expected,

a request is sent to: http://localhost:3200/login-saml (FE)

while expected url is : localhost:8080/login (BE)

[image]
here is all my code:

```
<template>
  <!-- Sing in  Form -->
  <section class="sign-in" style="padding-top: 65px">
    <div class="container">
      <form v-bind:action="urlLogin" method="post" ref="form">
        <input type="text" id="SAMLRequest" name="SAMLRequest" v-model="SAMLRequest">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'LoginPage',
  data() {
    return {
      urlLogin: '',
      SAMLRequest: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/rest/v2/sso/loginInfo`)
        .then(response => {
          this.urlLogin = response.data.urlLogin;
          this.SAMLRequest = response.data.samlrequest;
          this.$refs.form.submit();
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem? do you have an error? or something else?

Comment: @MahEs I have updated the question with error details, hope you can check it for me

Comment: does your axios call returns 200 ? can you provide a log of your response? i'm not usre, but i think problem might be that your axios url is a local url.

Comment: @MahEs axios returns 200, everything works fine if I remove this.$refs.form.submit(); and click by hand

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of problem that you have is the `action` attribute that you set in your form. I don't know about the back-end structure of your site ( it is `node-js` or `php` or ... ), but when you are using `axios` in your project actually you don't need to use normal way of form submitting (using `:action` and a submit button to submit form). You could handle it with the help of **axios** methods. Here is a way that I implement to submit a form (for example a register form) with a vue component:

```html
<template>
  <!-- Sing in  Form -->
  <section>
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            <label for="usernameId">username:</label>  
            <input type="text" id="usernameId" name="username" v-model="username">

            <label for="emailId">email:</label>  
            <input type="email" id="emailId" name="email" v-model="email">

            <label for="passwordId">password:</label>  
            <input type="password" id="passwordId" name="password" v-model="password">

            <button type="button" @click="postData">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'formCompo',
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
      postData: function() {
        let postVar = {
            username: this.username,
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
        };
        /* put your back-end url in axios.post() for example http://localhost:3200/saml-... */
        axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/stack-overflow/axios-test/datafind.php`, postVar).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
      }
  },

  mounted() {
    /* put the url that you want to get data from back-end in post.get() */
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/stack-overflow/axios-test/dataGet.php`)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.username = response.data.username;
          this.email = response.data.email;
          this.password = response.data.password;
          this.postData();
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        })
        
  }
}
</script>
```

You could comment only the `<form>` tag in the above code to see that it works again without any problem. In the code above I used the `postData` method to post data to back-end with axios. This method could be called when the button is clicked or in the `mounted()` hook. If you use this method in your project you don't need to use `urlLogin` data but you can define conditions that when you use auto submit (in mounted hook) or using button for submitting data. If you used the script that I posted and your problem remained I guess that the problem is from `CORS policy` that has its own solution depends on your back-end structure. for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883984/vue-axios-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin) is a good solution in my opinion if you use `php` in your back-end.